# Does cl option in windows makefile will accepts -std=c++11 flag?

Tags: c++11, makefile, visual-studio-2017

I have written sample Makefile in windows which uses cl option from visual studio 2017. It causes the warnings as follow 
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'

Follow the below steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2017
2. Write any simple c++ code and compile with using then we can see the warning

```
   cl <filename>.cpp /std=c++11
```

Does it mean VS2017 by default it will support c++11, so cl option omitting c++11 flag (or) is there something else for throwing warning by cl.exe?

Can anyone please clarify regarding this issue?

Thanks,

Hari

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017).  `cl` only accepts the options `/std:c++14`, `/std:c++17`, and `/std:c++latest`.

C++11 features are already enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Examining the output of `cl.exe /?` for MSVC 2017, I found:

```
/std:<c++14|c++17|c++latest> C++ standard version
    c++14 – ISO/IEC 14882:2014 (default)
    c++17 – ISO/IEC 14882:2017
    c++latest – latest draft standard (feature set subject to change)
```

It appears that:

- There is no switch for strict C++11 compatibility.
- The correct syntax is `/std:...`, not `-std=...`